# How to select max value and max value count by group

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which i have to calculate max value and count of (calculate max value) group by name and sex.

```
sample input:  

name sex age  
 A    F  2  
 A    F  3  
 A    M  4  
 B    F  6  
 B    M  7  
 B    M  7  
 B    F  4  
 C    M  8  
 C    M  8  
 C    M  8  
 C    M  3  
 C    F  1  
 C    F 10  
 C    F 10  

Sample Output:  
name    sex max_age count_max_age
A        F        3          1
A        M        4          1
B        F        6          1
B        M        7          2
C        F       10          2
C        M        8          3
```

I have tried

```
select name,sex,max(age) as max_age , count(max_age) from table_1 group by name ,sex
```

I am getting an error

```
Unknown column max_age in fieldlist
```

please suggest any modifications required in above query.
Thanks in advance

Comment: add table structure in your question

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table's structure, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it.

Comment: Your query looks fine to me.  You should add some input and output data.  Actually, I doubt the above query is what generated that error.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I have shared the sample input and output table's.Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(max_age), name, sex FROM (
  SELECT name, sex, max(age) as max_age from table_1 group by name, sex
) as max_age_group group by name, sex
```

query will not understand the alias on the same level, however you can make it as a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery and join like below

```
select 
    t1.name, t1.sex, max_age, count(max_age) as countofmaxage 
from 
    (select name, sex, max(age) as max_age 
     from t 
     group by name, sex) t1 
join 
    t on t1.name = t.name and t1.sex = t.sex and t1.max_age = t.age
group by 
    t1.name, t1.sex, max_age
```

Output:

```
name    sex max_age countofmaxage
----------------------------------
A        F     3            1
A        M     4            1
B        F     6            1
B        M     7            2
C        F     10           2
C        M     8            3
```

[DEMO in fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8cac97ccaa9214ff570bd76e5dd32bca)